# storing a mongoose (node.js orm) query result

Tags: mongodb, node.js, mongoose

Is there anyway to do something like:

```
var first_user = User.find({ _id: user_id }).first();
```

using the *mongoose* ORM? http://github.com/LearnBoost/mongoose

What I'm trying to do is to store the returned result of the query for later use.

When I use the above, all I get returned into the `var first_user` is the *QueryWriter* object.

Comment: Can you just use "findOne". I'm not totally familiar with Mongoose, but the "findOne" function is pretty consistent in most of the drivers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can access the results of a mongoose query through a passed callback. You'll find that mongoose, like most node.js modules, makes extensive use of async callbacks. Mongoose also provides a nice method for returning an object by its id, and if you want to use this result outside of the scope of the callback, you can do it like this:

```
var first_user;
User.findById(user_id, function(user){
  first_user = user;
});
```

For other mongoose API calls, I recommend looking at the mongoose tests for a good reference. Check out http://github.com/LearnBoost/mongoose/blob/master/tests/integration/model.test.js

Comment: Thanks. It occurred to me after posting that my desired syntax, had it been available would by its nature block.